# C - How to convert int values into a binary uint8 message

Tags: c, sockets, binary

So I have the following Int Array with 5 values

```
int guess[5]= { 1 , 4 , 7 , 3 , 0 } // Testguess
```

What I want to have in the end is a uint16, or actually 2 uint8 values representing those values in binary. The LSB (bit 15) is used for a flag which is irrelevant for now. In the end I want to transfer this message via a socket.

So with the values stated above I want to get the following message:
(I will seperate the different values with spaces to make it more clear)

`X 000 011 111 100 001`

Note that the values are from right to left.

The X is a flag, which is basically a xor with all bits, but I think I can figure this out for myself.

I am pretty new to C and want to know good solutions for the following tasks.

- How to convert the values of the int Array into binaries?
- How to write those binary values into the uint16?
- How to split this result uint16 into 2 uint8s?

I am pretty much failing finding a good approach to this. I was thinking about using shifts with the range of 3 for the writing, but I am not sure how to get those binaries, maybe doing & 0x2 or something?

Like I said I am still pretty new to C and am happy for every help.

Comment: The `X` bit that you describe as a "flag, which is basically a xor with all bits" is likely a "parity bit". There are surprisingly efficient ways to compute parity without scanning all the bits individually. See this item in the [bithacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) page for one example. Read the rest of the page for lots of interesting bit-twiddling tricks. Also, do take time to play with the bitwise arithmetic operators to get a better feel for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit shift in each `guess[]`.

```
int guess[5]= { 1 , 4 , 7 , 3 , 0 } // Testguess
uint16_t y = 0;
unsigned i;
for (i = 0; i < 15; i += 3) {
  y |= (guess[i] & 7) << i;
}
if (tbd()) { // set the X bit
  y |= 0x8000; 
}
uint8_t lsbyte = (uint8_t) y;
uint8_t msbyte = (uint8_t) (y >> 8);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, could you please explain to me what the |= operator does?

Comment: `a |= b` is the same as `a = a | b`.  That is to take each bit of `a` and "or" it with each bit of `b`, assigning the answer to `a`.  e.g. 5 or 12 is 13.  (0101 or 1100 --> 1101).

Answer (score 2):

Use some bit shifting:

```
int guess[5]= { 1 , 4 , 7 , 3 , 0 } // Testguess
int output = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    output |= (guess[i] & 0x7) << (i * 3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using pointers of the desired type should work fine.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    uint8_t* x = (void*) guess[i];
}
```

But as someone else stated earlier since your goal is to obtain the binary representation for use in networking you may want to use appropriate functions for the task.

Some architectures are little endians others are big endians while the network standard is just one.